# drawing lines in a Lilypond score algorithmically

Tags: scheme, lilypond

In reference to [this post](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/131421/contemporary-music-note-group-notation) I would like to write a scheme function in Lilypond which would help me not to manually define the position of each point of the lines.

Here a simplified example of the problem:

```
\version "2.24.1"

samplePath = 
    #'(
        (moveto -4.96 0)
        (lineto -1.7 2)
        (moveto 1 0)
        (lineto -1.7 2)
        )

\score {
    \new Staff {
        \time 1/4
        \clef "treble"
        \override Beam.positions = #'(5 . 5)
        \override Beam.transparent = ##t
        g'8 d'^\markup \path #0.1 #samplePath
    }
    \layout {}
}
```

I have 2 8th notes to which I removed the beam. Then on top of these notes I add a `\markup` statement which calls `samplePath`, a function which draws diagonal lines from the top of the note stems to a fixed point (`(-1.7 2)` in this case).

How I could formulate a Scheme function that accepts a list of notes and draws the lines that converge to one point getting the top position of each note stems? Is it even possible?

I took inspiration from [this manual page](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/learning/advanced-tweaks-with-scheme) but not knowing `scheme` and being a beginner in Lilypond I struggle to understand the Internal Documentation.

Thank you!